# Analyse these algorithms using Big-O notation (by using number of comparisons, and number of copying operations)

Tags: algorithm, sorting, big-o, bubble-sort

This is the code for my "optimised" bubble sort:

```
import random
n = 20                              #Create Variable for length of the array
array = []                          #Create array
y = 0
z = 0

for i in range(n):      #Generate random elements to fill the array to specified length
    x = random.randint(1, 1000)
    array.append(x)




for i in range(n-1):                #Create a for loop with range (length of array - 1)
    for e in range(0, n-1):       #Create a for loop with range (length of array - incremented integer of loop - 1)
        if array[e] > array[e+1]:  #If position is greater than next position: 
            array[e], array[e+1] = array[e+1], array[e] #Swap the elements
        y = y + 1
    z = z + 1
print("""BubbleSort.py

Sorted Array: """, array)
print("Number of Times Scanned: ", z, ", With A Total Of: ", y, " Comparisons.")
```

This is the code for my normal bubble sort:

```
import random
n = 20                              #Create Variable for length of the array
array = []                          #Create array
y = 0
z = 0

for i in range(n):      #Generate random elements to fill the array to specified length
    x = random.randint(1, 1000)
    array.append(x)




for i in range(n-1):                #Create a for loop with range (length of array - 1)
    for e in range(0, n-1):       #Create a for loop with range (length of array - incremented integer of loop - 1)
        if array[e] > array[e+1]:  #If position is greater than next position: 
            array[e], array[e+1] = array[e+1], array[e] #Swap the elements
        y = y + 1
    z = z + 1
print("""BubbleSort.py

Sorted Array: """, array)
print("Number of Times Scanned: ", z, ", With A Total Of: ", y, " Comparisons.")
```

My brain is being dumb today and for some reason i can't wrap my head around analysing these.
I thought it was n(n-1)/2 for # of Comparisons, and n-1 for # of copying operations for the normal but i realise that doesn't seem right.

What are the # of comparisons and # of copying operations for both and how do i work that out?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'm not entirely sure about your syntax. When you write something like

```
for i in range(n - timesscanned)
  ...
  timesscanned = timesscanned + 1
```

Is the range evaluated only once in the beginning or with every iteration of the loop? If it's the first, the `timescanned` in the `range` is useless because it`s initialized to 0. If it's the second, your optimized algorithm is wrong because it only handles half the array.

And you also seem to have different types of ranges. One time you write

```
for i in range(0, n)
```

Another time you write

```
for i in range(numOfElements)
```

What's the difference between those two?

Second, what your "optimized" approach is counting in the variable `y` is not the number of comparisons but the number of swaps, because you are only incrementing that value if the two compared values are in the wrong order.

And third, what's the difference between the variable `timesscanned` and `z`? They are both initialized to 0 and incremented for every iteration of the outer loops. Depending on the semantics of the range (see above) in the end they are both either `n` or `n/2`

Finally, yes the worst case (and in the naive implementation also the "always" case) for the number of comparisons is O(n^2), and the worst case for the number of swaps (in an array which is sorted descending) is also O(n^2).

EDIT

What you can do to optimise the naive version of bubble sort is the following two things

1. As in each iteration of the outer loop the biggest currently unsorted element is "bubbled" up towards the end of the array. So in the `x`th iteration of the outer loop, the inner loop doesn't need to iterate the whole array any more, but can skip checking the last `x` elements.
2. If during one iteration of the inner loop no swapping happened at all, the array is sorted correctly. Thus the algorithm can stop. The naive approach will do all iterations and checks, even if the original array is already sorted. An optimized version will iterate a sorted array only a single time.

Comment: Sorry about my stupid code, i've fixed it up a bit now.
So firstly, I've gotten rid of timesScanned and just left z.

The range of the "for i in range(n - timesScanned" (now n-z) is evaluated at the beginning of each loop. But im not sure what you mean by it only handles half the array as when run it works fine.
Secondly, i've fixed the placement of y so it does count the number of comparisons instead thank you.

Comment: If `range(n-z)` is evaluated at every iteration, and `z` is incremented in every iteration of this loop, this is equivalent to `range(n/2)`. Thus, the outer loop is iterated only n/2 times. But in each iteration of the outer loop only one element can be placed at its correct position. So if you have n elements to sort, you need n iterations of the outer loop, but you only have n/2. It may look like it works, if the array is not "too unsorted", but it won't solve the worst case (reverse sorted array)

Comment: BTW now after your edit, both of your codeblocks are identical